# Magento disable My Cart block from reviews page

Tags: magento, cart, review

I am trying to disable My Cart block from the reviews page, It is not displaying on my product page until I click reviews. I also need to change the buy box to include a size dropdown like on the product page.

I tried display:none in the CSS, but it still takes up space which shifts my entire page out of place.

Comment: Can you show some code of what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding,i concluded with this solution

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
<default>
</default>
<review_product_list>
    <remove name="cart_sidebar" />
</review_product_list>
</layout>
```

The above code will remove **mycart block (right side) from only review page**.If you want to remove it from every page write : `<remove name="cart_sidebar" />` between `<default>` tag.
Write the following code in local.xml.
path:magento_folder/app/design/frontend/mytheme(your_package_folder)/neo(your_theme_folder)/layout/local.xml